# How to install JDBC driver on Databricks Cluster?

Tags: jdbc, etl, databricks, cx-oracle, argument-dependent-lookup

I'm trying to get the data from my Oracle Database to a Databricks Cluster. But I think I'm doing it wrong:

On the cluster library I just installed the ojdbc8.jar and then after that I opened a notebook and did this to connect:

```
CREATE TABLE oracle_table
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  dbtable 'table_name',
  driver 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
  user 'username',
  password 'pasword',
  url 'jdbc:oracle:thin://@<hostname>:1521/<db>')
```

And it says:
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified

Can someone help? I've been reading documentations but there's no clear instruction on how I should actually install this jar step by step. I might be using the wrong jar? Thanks!

Comment: from error message, you have a problem not with driver (there will be another error in this case), but with URL - do you really need to specify `@` in it?

Comment: No, I tried to fix the url several times - it all boils down to driver not being installed properly. Not sure how to install it at this point.

Comment: How do install it?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to set this up in Python/PySpark as follows:

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostName:port/databaseName"

connectionProperties = {
    "user" : username,
    "password" : password,
    "driver" : "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
}

query = "(select * from mySchema.myTable )"

df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=query1, properties=connectionProperties)
```

I am using the Oracle JDBC Thin Driver instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.5.0.0.0, as available on the Oracle webpages. The current version is 21.7 I think, but it should work the same way.

Check [this link](https://shekhargulati.com/2019/01/22/solution-ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-descriptor/) to understand the two different notations for jdbc URLs